# segue with code and Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How to make a segue with code and Collection View?

Just to test I could change the color of each cell when I click. So it selects well each cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {  
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } 
}
```

But then instead of changing the color I make the segue only with code. The same code works in a Table View but it doesn't here with a Collection View. What am I missing? (I have no Navigation Controller, by the way)

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {  
    let detailController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondlViewController") as! SecondViewController

    presentViewController(detailController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: you can simply create detailControler object by calling constructor like 

var detailController = DetailController();

try this

Answer (score 1):

did you try :

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("Identifier", sender: self)
```